# How can I use a Javascript object/map as queue

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, queue

Right now I have a queue (JS array) that is used to store players waiting for a game. I need the FIFO property of a queue so that players who were added to the queue first, get put in a new game first. The problem with a queue is that it doesnt have constant time lookup. It would be great if I could have a map that kept track of the order of insertion (i know that relying on a map to do this is JS is not reliable). If I give the property a value for its insertion order, it would need to be updated if someone leaves the queue, so that isnt helpful either. Anyway around this? A way to get constant lookup and maintain insertion order?

Comment: Would a linked list work?

Comment: Linked list has the same look up cost as an array queue

Comment: Can you give me some feedback as to whether my answer was useful or not? I think it fits the requirements you mentioned, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have memory constraints, maybe you can maintain a map with the queue implemented as a double linked list. Here is a sample implementation:

```
function Queue() {
    var oldestRequest,
        newestRequest,
        map = {};

    this.addUser = function(userID) {
        var newRequest = { userID: userID };
        map[userID] = newRequest;

        // Set this as the oldest request if it is the first request
        if (!oldestRequest) {
            oldestRequest = newRequest;
        }

        // If this isn't the first request, add it to the end of the list
        if (newestRequest) {
            newestRequest.next = newRequest;
            newRequest.previous = newestRequest;
        }

        newestRequest = newRequest;
    };

    this.nextUser = function() {
        // If we don't have any requests, undefined is returned
        if (oldestRequest) {
           var request = oldestRequest;
           oldestRequest = request.next;
           delete map[request.userID];

           // Make sure we don't hang on to references to users
           // that are out of the queue
           if (oldestRequest) {
               delete oldestRequest.previous;
           }

           // This is the last request in the queue so "empty" it
           if (request === newestRequest) {
               newestRequest = undefined;
           }

           return request;
        }
    };

    this.removeUser = function(userID) {
        var request = map[userID];
        delete map[userID];

        if (request.previous) {
            request.previous.next = request.next;
        }

        if (request.next) {
            request.next.previous = request.previous;
        }
    };

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map together with a queue to provide constant time access. Below is the implementation in TypeScript 4.2. `Map` is used instead of `Object` to provide [better performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) in addition and removal of values.

```
// TypeScript typing
export type KeyValuePair<K, V> = [ K, V ]

interface ValueData<V> {
  value: V
  refCount: number
}

// Public classes
export class MapQueue<K, V> {
  readonly #queue: Array<KeyValuePair<K, V>>
  readonly #map: Map<K, ValueData<V>>

  constructor () {
    this.#queue = []
    this.#map = new Map()
  }

  get length (): number {
    return this.#queue.length
  }

  unshiftOne (pair: KeyValuePair<K, V>): number {
    const [key, value] = pair
    const valueData = this.#map.get(key)
    if (valueData !== undefined) {
      if (valueData.value !== value) {
        throw new Error(`Key ${String(key)} with different value already exists`)
      }
      valueData.refCount++
    } else {
      this.#map.set(key, {
        value,
        refCount: 1
      })
    }
    return this.#queue.unshift(pair)
  }

  pop (): KeyValuePair<K, V> | undefined {
    const result = this.#queue.pop()
    if (result !== undefined) {
      const valueData = this.#map.get(result[0])
      if (valueData !== undefined) {
        valueData.refCount--
        if (valueData.refCount === 0) {
          this.#map.delete(result[0])
        }
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  get (key: K): V | undefined {
    return this.#map.get(key)?.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply build the map as a linked list ? I.e. keeping track of the head and tail of the "map-queue" so to easily pop out the last element/push a new element while keeping good performance for getting a specific element.

Comment: @tomfl I think you can have your own suggestion implemented and post it here as an answer. My comment on your suggestion to use linked list:
1. How you are going to handle to the same key value pair being put into the queue multiple times?
2. If someone want to get the value at particular index in the queue, index lookup using array is obviously faster than traversing through the linked list.